# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ,error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on the below code but I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" every time I call the component (<>ItemsIndex />)

I have tried to add {this.props.items && this.props.items.map()} bur when I did that the page keep loading.

```
  class ItemsIndex extends Component { 
.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.


    static async getInitialProps() {
        const items = await lists.methods.getItems().call();
        return { items };
      }

      renderItems() {
        const list = this.props.items.map(async address => {

          return {
                  header: address,
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: That is because this.props.items is undefined and you must have null check for it

Comment: Shouldn't put anything `async` in `render()`

Answer (score 1):

Items is not an array yet since getInitialProps is asynchronous. It is trying to call map on a non array.

```
if (this.props.items) {

   this.props.items.map(async address => {
       //do stuff
   });

}
```

Comment: thanks, the error fixed but still the page is not rendering the array and keeps loading :(